# Can I omit the second "if"?

Tags: sentence-construction

*Check if the value is within the specified range and (if) there are no cracks in the product.

Do I need to write if twice in this case?

*Check if there is no dirt on the surface and if there is no dust on the floor.

Also, which part can I remove from the sentence in this case?

Comment: 'Check *that*' not 'check if'.